# Is one-to-one relationship required?

Tags: database-design

I have these three tables on my database:
[image]

There is a **one-to-one** relationship between `Code` and `Aggregation` table (an `AggregationId` is always a `CodeId`. And of course, a `CodeId` is unique). **Note**: A `Code.CodeId` doesn't need to be in `Aggregation` table.

There is a **one-to-many** relationship between `Aggregation` and `AggregationChildren` table (an aggregation will have one or more children).

I think I'm wasting a lot of space repeating a `NVARCHAR(20)` data in three tables `Code.CodeId`, `Aggregation.AggregationId` and `AggregationChildren.AggregationId`.

<s>By the way, `AggregationChildren.</s>

What do you think?

I think I can delete `Aggregation` and `AggregationChildren` tables.Then, add two new columns to `Code` table:
One to indicate to replace `Aggregation.AggregationId`.
Another one to replace `AggregationChildren.Position`.

Comment: You need to think more about this design before implementing.  I recommend using auto incrementing integer columns for the primary key in all tables for performance reasons.  Use these integer columns as foreign keys in the other tables that require it.  By eliminating the Aggregation and Aggregation Children tables as you suggest, you are simply making one big table which is a separate headache altogether.

Answer (score 1):

If the multiple use of `NVARCHAR(20)` bothers you, change the type to `INT` and adapt the `Code` table to have two columns: `ID (INT)` and `Name (NVARCHAR(20))`.

Comment: No, because CodeId must be unique, and if I add an ID column I will have two index.

Comment: 2 indices - who cares. You gain a lot of speed, comparing strings is SLOW. And uniqueness can still be enforced.

Comment: I'm not asking this.

Comment: And I'm not going to work with new ID column, I will use CodeId column to search and avoid duplicates. It has not seen to add a new column that it's not going to be use. Sorry, but your answer doesn't answer my question.

Comment: If CodeID must be unique and you collapse your design into one table, how to you think that is going to work?  You will have one aggregation per code and one aggregation child per aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

From your definition the relationship is 1 to (0,1).  This is different than a strict 1 to 1 relationship, and is normally modeled as you have done.  Your model is the one I would use.

If aggregation child can only belong to one aggregation, you will want a unique id on that column.

CodeId is the natural key, however this does not necessarily make it a good primary key.  You may want to consider using a surrogate key for a couple of reasons:

- If CodeId could ever change you will not need to cascade the change across multiple tables.
- Numeric surrogate keys tend to perform better as foreign keys.  However, a list of aggregations or aggregation children would require joining one or more times to the code table.